# Django collectstatic error

Tags: python, django

Error:

```
This will overwrite existing files!

  Are you sure you want to do this?
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>

  execute_manager(settings)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager

  utility.execute()

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute

  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv

  self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute

  output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle

  return self.handle_noargs(**options)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs

  collected = self.collect()

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 113, in collect

  handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 287, in copy_file

  if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 219, in delete_file

  self.storage.modified_time(prefixed_path)

  File "D:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 264, in modified_time

  return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(self.path(name)))

  ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
(env) D:\CODE\wamp\www\lezcheung\lezcms>
```

Anyone know help me?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's caused by files being collected by `collectstatic` having outrageously inaccurate last modified timestamps (like before 1970). Try searching google for tools that allow you to modify your files' last modified dates and change them to something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I discoreved.

This is just cause I put some fonts in /static/fonts/ and the django don't accept fonts on Static Folder. So, i changed this files to /media/fonts/.

Worked! :D